# GetRequestStream() timeout an error after second time

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I have some problems with code. I'm using HttpWebRequest class to do operations

Code as bellow:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)768;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
//ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 5;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverName + authorizePath);
request.Abort();
byte[] bearerMatch = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");

//request.Proxy = null; //<TNI_20180808
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Timeout = 100;
//request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(bearerMatch);

 string content = String.Format(authorizeBody, login, password);
 content = "{" + content + "}";

 try
 {
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
     {
         writer.Write(content);
     }

     using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
     {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             var responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
             token = responseContent.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
         }
         //response.Close();
         //request.Abort();
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

     throw ex;
 }
```

Until third operation everything is okey, unfortunately i don't know what to do. When application is trying to create request third time there is an timeout error:

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)

I think that there is an opportunity to solve this with closing request and response in a proper way but i don't know how to do this. After increasing ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit operations were getting completed correctly.

Can you help me please? How should i abort or close request/response in a good way?

Thank you!

Comment: I wondering if the connections are closing.  There may be a limit to the number on connection from same IP.  Or its failing because the credentials are failing.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if there are any differences in the http headers between the working and non working.  The timeout may not be the real root cause of the issue.

Comment: I already trying to increasing DefaultConnectionLimit so i'm almost sure that this is it. Credentials are good.

Comment: What about the other headers?